# Request validation with quarkus

Tags: validation, quarkus, http-request-parameters

I have a REST Enspoint

...
@GET
public Response read (@Valid Param parameters) {

}
...

How can I catch this Exception to handle this in Quarkus?
Is there a special Exceptionhandler available?

Comment: https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#exception-mapping

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the exception by using:

```
@Provider
public class MyViolationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ValidationException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ValidationException exception) {
        // do something
    }

}
```

You can draw inspiration for how to handle things by looking at the [built-in](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/2.14.0.Final/extensions/hibernate-validator/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/hibernate/validator/runtime/jaxrs/ResteasyReactiveViolationExceptionMapper.java) exception mapper.

Comment: Many thanks. I found the error. I had a ExcepionMapper<Exception> and was wondering why it was not called. It seem that inheritance depth matters.

Comment: It does matter - this is specified by the JAX-RS specification